# List attributes by a common criteria attribute

Tags: xml, loops, xquery

I have a question dealing with Xquery.
My objective is to display into different elements all the elements from a loop that have the same attribute but differ for another one. It's been 48 hours I'm stuck on that, I can't go forward! :(

here an example of the type of tables that i've got:

```
<people>
<crazy id="123" firstname="John" lastname="Fool" score="20">
<crazy id="123" firstname="John" lastname="Fool" score="80">
<crazy id="123" firstname="John" lastname="Fool" score="77">
<crazy id="123" firstname="John" lastname="Fool" score="49">
<crazy id="789" firstname="Lea" lastname="Dumb" score="54">
<crazy id="789" firstname="Lea" lastname="Dumb" score="89">
<crazy id="789" firstname="Lea" lastname="Dumb" score="99">
<crazy id="789" firstname="Lea" lastname="Dumb" score="4">
<crazy id="247" firstname="Paul" lastname="Duck" score="16">
<crazy id="247" firstname="Paul" lastname="Duck" score="91">
<crazy id="247" firstname="Paul" lastname="Duck" score="22">
<crazy id="247" firstname="Paul" lastname="Duck" score="31">
</people>
```

I would like to get something like that :

```
<person>247</person>
```

(This is a list of the "id" of people that have less 2 score of more than the value "50".

I've got something like this

```
 let $calc:= (

  for $boucle in people where ($boucle/@score>="50")
  return $boucle

)
```

Now i'd like to list the number of people that have less than 2 "score" greater than 50.
but I don't know how to proceed :( :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, but I think it's this:

```
for $id in distinct-values(//crazy/@id)
  where count(//crazy[@id = $id and number(@score) gt  50]) lt 2
return <person>{$id}</person>
```